# NumPy - Does not sort array properly without padding zeros

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have array elements of the form:

```
['A 0', 'A 10', 'A 1', 'A 100', 'A 20', 'A 200']
```

When I try to sort it with np.sort(), it does not sort properly. How to sort the array properly?

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array(['A 0', 'A 10', 'A 1', 'A 100', 'A 20', 'A 200'])
A = np.sort(A)
print A
```

**Output**

```
['A 0' 'A 1' 'A 10' 'A 100' 'A 20' 'A 200']
```

**Desired output**

```
['A 0' 'A 1' 'A 10' 'A 20' 'A 100' 'A 200']
```

Comment: what is wrong about it? it looks fine from here

Comment: It should sort it as ['A 0' 'A 1' 'A 10' 'A 20' 'A 100' 'A 200'].

Comment: You are sorting strings! Why do you expect anything but a lexical sorting here?

Comment: What's the purpose of using numpy if you're handling strings anyway? Strings are storted in [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a [natural sort](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/). Python doesn't come with one, and NumPy certainly isn't the library to look for one in.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to load the data as two separate columns: the text part and the numeric part.  This works:

```
>>> lst = ['A 0', 'A 10', 'A 1', 'A 100', 'A 20', 'A 200']
>>> A = np.loadtxt(lst, dtype=[('text', 'S4'), ('numbers', int)])
>>> A.sort(order='numbers')
>>> A
array([('A', 0), ('A', 1), ('A', 10), ('A', 20), ('A', 100), ('A', 200)], ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you should tell it how it is supposed to do it, like for example:

```
lst.sort(key=lambda s: int(s[2:]))
```

Comment: This is not a NumPy solution.